# What's a neutral/negative word for 'impress'?

Tags: word-request, verbs

I am looking for a verb to describe something giving someone a bad/unpleasant impression, Ex:

> Jack was released from prison for almost five years. Someone asked him what was his impression about the prison experience. He replied in dismay, "No decent food, no sunshine, no friend…",  "that's what ___(a verb similar with 'impress' but in neutral/negative connotation) me the most about prison experience"

What's the verb for it?

Comment: I should impress upon you that **impress** doesn't always have positive connotations.

Comment: You could reference Johnny Cash's song "Folsom Prison Blues" for some good examples of this feeling.  (It is a "country" song, so some of the phrasing is a little rural.) https://youtu.be/6ZPToXstS8M

Comment: Dictionaries will affirm what @Tᴚoɯɐuo says. "To affect (someone) strongly and [often favourably](https://www.wordnik.com/words/impress)"; _often_ implies that the word can be (and is) used for negative impressions.

Comment: You could use the phrase "stuck with me".

Comment: _"That's what dismayed me the most about the prison experience"._ ...or... _"bummed me out"_ in the vernacular. Also consider _demoralized_.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments indicate, "impress" by definition does not **always** carry a positive connotation.  However, as you correctly surmise, "impress" and "impressed" often do carry positive connotations.  To use "impress" to indicate something has made an imprint on something else you generally use a preposition.

"I would like to impress upon you," means something entirely different than. "I would like to impress you." That being said, "impression" always means something has made an imprint on something else without positive or negative connotations.

> Your sentence can be written, "Those are my impressions of prison."

Comment: thanks. is there a verb for this question?